# Bitmap or smooth edge for vintage graphic?

Tags: bitmap, vintage

I am working on a high resolution **vintage graphic** retouching.

The original image is bitmap mode, I try to make it smooth for large size printing. But after it I am confusing if the smooth edge is better for vantage graphic? here is a sample:

[image]
Original bitmap

[image]
Smooth

Which one you think is better for **vintage graphic**?

Comment: Hi bard, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Comment: I vote for smooth!